# Font Awesome with Bootstrap SASS

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, font-awesome

I have a rails 4 app.

My font awesome icons have worked until recently. Now, instead of my social media icons, i have black squares (I can't see why those have replaced the coloured icons I've been using). The links work. The  tags are the same as they always have been and the same as the font awesome directions.

I installed font awesome using the sass gem. I require font-awesome, just above self in my application.css.scss.

I have the current gem installed (4.2.0).

For what it's worth - this is my footer with the links I'm using:

```
<a href="https://www.youtube.com/user/Coalfacer"> <i class="fa fa-youtube fa-2x"></i> </a>
```

Any advice?

Thank you

Comment: If you have chrome developer tools, firebug or anything like that you can check a few things. Has the font downloaded? If it's not found there's your problem. If it hasn't attempted to download at all perhaps you don't have the correct font declaration. Also check your `<i>` element and see if the FontAwesome classes have been overwritten by anything.

Comment: thanks James. There aren't any divs overriding the i class. I't defined in the way that FA sets out. How do I check whether the font has downloaded?

Comment: In Chrome developer tools you can look at the network tab and it shows all requests for resources. You can also sort for just fonts to see if the font file was downloaded. I assume that firebug and IE dev tools (11 at least) will have something similar. Failing all  of that you could use fiddler to trace the requests but that's not ideal, and won't work if it's loaded from the cache.

Comment: Ahhh. I get a 404 error that the font awesome fonts are not found. How do I fix that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Chrome developer tools, firebug or any similar type of tools to check a few things. Firstly you want to make sure the font has downloaded. Using the network tab of Chrome developer tools, you can see outgoing requests and the responses that were made in order to serve the page. Check to see if a request was made for the font file.

Two possible scenarios are the

1. No request was made for the font. This would indicate a problem with your font declarations in the `@media` query of your CSS file.
2. A request was made for the font but it returned an error code.

If an error code is returned you need to determine why that is the case. For example a 404 indicates that the server could not locate the requested file in the specified location, so obviously you need to check that the file is there. Another thing to check is that the web server is configured to respond correctly to requests for fonts by serving the files. I have come across cases where 404 errors are thrown because the web server does not serve, or is explicitly disallowing requests for `.woff` files, which makes the 404 error somewhat misleading.

If the request for the font files is being made and the server is responding with a success code (200, 302 etc), then it may be a problem with the styling of your HTML element.

Using the tools mentioned above you can also 'Inspect' the HTML element, generally by right clicking on it and selecting a menu option along those lines (In chrome it is 'Inspect Element'). You should be able to see a rundown of each element and where the styles are coming from similar to this image.

[image: Example screenshot of chrome developer tools, inspecting an element]

There you should be able to find out if something is overriding your styles.